# Importing data from API to Revit software using C# Add-in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, integration, revit-api

**Question:**
I'm currently working on a C# Add-in for Revit and need to import data (JSON/XML/or any other format) from an C# Web API into the Revit software. I have searched for specific documentation or videos on this topic, but haven't found any helpful resources so far.

Could someone provide guidance on how to import data from an API into Revit using a C# Add-in? Specifically, I'm looking for information on the following:

- How to establish a connection to the API from within the Revit Add-in.
- How to map the API data to Revit elements or
  parameters.

I would greatly appreciate any code examples, references to relevant documentation, or any other resources that can help me achieve this functionality in my Revit Add-in.

*Thank you in advance for your assistance!*

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is too much. Your asking for a detailed tutorial. StackOverflow is best used when you've got a single specific question.

Comment: Follow this: https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/tsarticles/ts/7I2bC1zUr4VjJ3U31uM66K.html then post here when you get stuck

Comment: @AndyWynn I deeply apologize for my inability to locate any videos or articles that explain how to post data from an external source (API) to Revit software. I would be grateful if you could kindly answer at least one of my questions.

Comment: I done a lot of research.  You can either import a CAD file.  CAD file have different format and you would need to build you model base on a CAD file format.  Or you can import an IFC file.  See following : https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-DE8B322A-A507-4E03-93EC-AA21F354E43B

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, I came here with the intention of answering your question, but to give a proper detailed answer will take several hours, and at that point it's less of a StackOverflow question and more of a consultancy gig.

Answer (score 0):

The official Autodesk FireRating SDK sample demonstrates all of these steps for a trivially simple use case:

https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/09/exporting-parameter-data-to-excel.html

The FireRatingCloud samples takes it to the next level:

https://github.com/jeremytammik/FireRatingCloud